# Excel pivot not recognising converted date from SQL as a date field

Tags: sql-server, excel, date, pivot-table

I've had a similar problem with dates before.
I'm querying a proprietary CMS database that stores dates as a string 'YYYYMMDD'.

I'm using...

```
convert(varchar(10),right(VarCompletionDate,2)+'/'+substring(VarCompletionDate,5,2)+'/'+left(varCompletionDate,4), 103)
```

to convert to 'DD/MM/YYYY' format. On the SQL side this *appears* to work but in Excel, the date is treated like a string rather than a date and I'm not getting the date filters that you would get with a proper date field...

[image]

what am I doing wrong here? is the `convert`converting *to* a varchar rather than a date? ...if I do `Convert(date,...` I get conversion errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find the answer!

`Convert(date,....)` 
Was the correct treatment to output a date format from SQL.
The Pivot table wouldn't recognise the field as a date after a refresh unless I recreated the pivot table - there must be some kind of data type persistence going on in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

In excel, you can select a data cell and confirm that the data does not have an apostrophe sign as suffix.
This forces excel to treat the data as text. If you do find it, please do a find and replace all in your selected data range.

[image]
If there is no apostrophe, select your data and go to Home>Number>format dropdown and then select long date or short date as the format type.
This will then bring up the date filters.

Comment: This is for a pivot table that connects to a SQL datasource - the problem is that Excel isn't recognising the data field that has been converted from text using `Convert`. There isn't an option to change the date format in the pivot table, so the date needs to be in a recognisable format coming out of SQL.